When responding to a bracha, many respond with v’chen l’mar. Would the appropriate response to a woman be v’chen l’maras?
When responding to a bracha, many respond with v’chen l’mar. Would the appropriate response to a woman be v’chen l’maras?

Sounds good to me!

Or maybe l'marta.

@meir that's what i say
